# When trying to send 10 emails (host is zoho) one after another (using PHP) I get an error

Tags: php, email, zoho

I am trying to send ~10 emails from php. It sends the first two emails but then after that I get "Swift_TransportException with message 'Connection could not be established with host smtp.zoho.com [ #0]'" .

I was told that it is most likely because of a limit on the amount of messages I can send per some time block (like 30 seconds). Is this true? I haven't been able to find any limit like this in zoho documentation.

EDIT: There must be some kind of limit like this because I added `sleep(45)` between every mail send call and now it works.

This is different from the duplicate question that is being suggested because it refers specifically to ZOHO/hosts limits in sending multiple emails in a short time span.

Comment: What does the code look like so we can help you?

Comment: `at most 150 emails.
(to no more than 50 recipients per message)
up to a combined size (including attachments) of 200 MB per day (from the web interface) or 40 MB (from an email program using Zoho Mail SMTP servers) and.
receive emails (including attachments) up to a total size of 300 MB per day.Aug 22, 2016`;-https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjt0sf9-b3UAhVKv48KHc4QCdEQFggkMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.lifewire.com%2Fmail-per-day-limit-zoho-mail-1170804&usg=AFQjCNFrig3oDdqVEUAg-F1_8Um1PXVyUg

Comment: @AlivetoDie I have seen this, but I am only sending 10 email (it fails after 2) and definitely less than 200mb (it is a few lines of text).

Comment: @hRdCoder I figured if there was some limit and someone had a reference, that would solve it for me. But the code is specific to laravel so maybe I will delete my question and ask again (so as to avoid xy problem).

Comment: so adding sleep(45) between send calls solved it